# Pass data from pop-up window back to javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `window.open` function in javascript that calls a page. I then want to grab the data from that page and return it to the javascript function.

Can anyone help me do this?

```
$("#popup").click(function(e) { 
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    e.preventDefault();
    window.open(url, 'authWindow', "width=800,height=436");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the page in the popup is in the ***same domain as yours,*** you can use window.opener to access data of the opener windows

In your current window :

```
var winopened;
$("#popup").click(function(e) { 
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    e.preventDefault();
    winopened = window.open(url, 'authWindow', "width=800,height=436");
});

if(winopened) {
  // call a function in the opened window : 
  res = winopened.functionInWindow();

}
```

hope it helped ...

Comment: But how to I get the data that is inside the window.open?

Answer (score 0):

`window.open` will return your window object.

```
var myWindow = window.open
```

Now you can play with myWindow.

Answer (score 0):

The other posters answers are correct, in that they'll give you the window object. I'm not sure that's what you were asking for.

Here's a very simple way you can return the HTML from the page, if that's the "data" you need (otherwise disregard this answer).

This uses jQuery's AJAX $.get function to load HTML from a webpage, more at https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

```
$.get(url, function( data ) {
   alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
});
```

From here, you can do whatever you like with the "data" variable that is returned - store it, parse it, show it...

Comment: I have to get the data from the pop-up window. I can't call the URL like I normally would. I'm just trying to grab the data once the popup window is done loading.

Comment: As long as the url points to a location, this should still return the data. For example, if you could put the value of "$(this).attr('href');" into your web browsers address bar and see some sort of HTML, that's what this function will return. If that totally doesn't help, could you clarify the meaning of "I can't call the URL like I normally would"?

Comment: The pop up is the instagram api which then goes to another URL of my own to get access token. So I can't just call the URL because the user needs to interact with the popup at first.

Comment: Does access token get loaded from your page and injected into the instagram page, or does the instagram page redirect to your URL with the access token?

Comment: instagram page redirects to my URL which displays the access token

Comment: I'd lean toward mimiz' answer then. Suppose on your page that the Instagram page redirects to you, you embed a javascript function (like mimiz' winopened.functionInWindow()) that returns the access key? Sounds like it has potential, though can't say I ever tried it.